# nodejs unistalled but still showing in cmd

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed **Nodejs** V12 but I want to use the V14. I uninstalled the V12 and installed the V14 but the V12 is still showing to be the version of **nodejs** installed instead of V14.

Can someone help me on how to find the solution.

Comment: This isn't a good question for StackOverflow. You don't seem to have a problem with a code.

Comment: Check your environment variables for node, where you can find the path

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have found the solution to this issue. It was in the GraalVM folder.

Comment: You can also try the npm package "n" to manage different version of node with a simple cli: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Comment: you can answer your solution